# I'm trying to automate google search page. Using Explicitly wait

Tags: selenium, webdriverwait

I'm just trying one string in search box like "testing" and then wait for the list of search option is visible and then printing the count of visible list.but getting 0 count. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class=\"gLFyf gsfi\"]")).sendKeys("testing");

    WebElement wait = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("UUbT9")));


    List<WebElement> search_List=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role=\'listbox\']/li/div//span"));
    System.out.println(search_List.size());

    for(WebElement we:search_List) {
        System.out.println(we.getText());
        if(we.getText().contains("testing types")) {
            we.click();
            break;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this cssSelector

```
   ul[class='erkvQe'] > li
```

Edit: Your code is working fine on my end. I am getting 10. If you are still getting 0. Try with my cssSelector. Both work.